# How are on-chain smart contracts stored?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, ethereum, solidity

I am currently learning about creating an own smart contracts platform, and it seems that there are two different types of smart contracts; installed and on-chain contracts. Installed are, in my opinion, quite easy to realise, but I am not getting a grip on the on-chain contracts.

I believe that for Ethereum and Hyperledger the contracts both are on-chain, but am wondering how the actual code is stored in the datastructure of the blockchain. And how does the stored code in a transaction execute at a certain moment for all other nodes?

Comment: To understand the EVM it is best to read the yellow paper: http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your intuition about the code for smart contracts being stored on-chain is correct -- in the case of Ethereum, it's in the form of a bytecode language called "Ethereum virtual machine (EVM) code". The execution of the smart contract code is part of the definition of the state transition function that defines the blockchain. For example, if a transaction is added into, say, block 7, the code execution mandated by that transaction will be executed by all nodes that download and validate block 7.